# Unable to set a dialog to be above, while opening multiple MatDialogs

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my Angular 11 app, I need to open multiple dialogs in the same time and control which one should be displayed over the other ones.

Basically, I have two different components to render the content of dialogs.
First, I have Basic dialogs that I can open using :

```
this.dialog.open(DialogBasicComponent, { data });
```

Additionally, I also have Notification dialogs that I can open using :

```
this.dialog.open(DialogNotificationComponent, { data });
```

My wish is to be able to open several of these dialogs at once and to always display the Notification dialogs above the Basic dialogs (keep them at the top of the stack).

At the moment, the dialog diplayed is always the last opened one. When I close it, the next in the stack is displayed, until the stack is empty. Unfortunately, I can't control the order in which I will open my dialogs as the need to open comes randomly.

My question is, can I control / manage the order of elements in the stack ?

Comment: What kind of notification is that? I have made the npm library which allows you to show confirm boxes or toast or similar notifications on top of the screen. It uses dynamic components as angular material, but it has little more advanced options, I could make StackBlitz example if you want?

Comment: Unfortunately I really need to use material dialogs as it's advanced notifications with images, buttons,etc.. And the style needs to be the same than the other dialogs